# Fast API: Handling exceptions globally

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to get the exception_handler to work on a large project. However, the exception handler is not running as expected. Any suggestions on what I could be missing?

Simplified Project Structure:

```
project
   __init__.py
   main.py
   common
     __init__.py
     ex_handler.py
```

I have the above project structure

app.py

```
app = FastAPI()

app.include_route(xyz)
```

I am importing this object into exception_handler.py which has code to handle all application-related exceptions

```
from project.main import app

@app.exception_handler(CustomException)
def handle_custom_ex(request: Request, exception: CustomException):
    ...
```

However, the exception handler is not running as expected. If I moved the exception_handler to app.py, it works.

Reference:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/?h=exception#install-custom-exception-handlers

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to go the other way, i.e. import `exception_handler` into your `main.py`:

```
# exception_handler.py
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
```

```
# main.py
from project.common.exception_handler import MyException
...
```

In the docs, they define the class in their `main.py` and then can use it in the FastAPI `app` object.

Note you'll need to do this from any module where you want to use the custom exception class.

Comment: Okay. If we go by this, main.py will become unmanageable over time. Any thoughts on how we can separate this out?

Comment: It seems like you're breaking out the exception handler as you want to use it in multiple modules/files across your project. I don't see how this will become unmanageable? You just have to add a single import line at the top?

Comment: Code doesn't run by itself - it has to be used / included in some way; how you do that efficiently depends on how the structure of your project is. Generally you can use sub applications if you have independent-ish applications bundled as one: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/

Comment: If you want to use your custom exception in `main.py` this is the easiest approach. If you're instead asking "How can I pass the FastAPI `app` instance around to different modules?" then we'd need to see a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand why your approach isn't working.